# Why does pandas.groupby keep the key?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to perform the following operations on a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

t = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                  'date': [datetime.date(2020,1,1), datetime.date(2020,1,2)] * 2, 
                  'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})

t.groupby('id').apply(lambda df: df.set_index('date').diff())
```

I got the result below

```
                    id  value
id date                  
1  2020-01-01  NaN    NaN
   2020-01-02  0.0    1.0
2  2020-01-01  NaN    NaN
   2020-01-02  0.0    2.0
```

My question is why the id column is kept. I expect the 'id' column disappear after this operation. What I want is

```
t.set_index(['id', 'date']).groupby(level=0).diff()
Out[92]: 
               value
id date             
1  2020-01-01    NaN
   2020-01-02    1.0
2  2020-01-01    NaN
   2020-01-02    2.0
```

Comment: when you run apply, you are essentially running a for loop on each sub dataframe, which has an id. The built-in functions/aggregations know how to separate the groupby key from the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

One idea is specify columns:

```
df = t.groupby('id')[['date','value']].apply(lambda df: df.set_index('date').diff())
```

I think reason is because used [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), so processing all columns in `groupby.apply`.